# Extracting error bars and point positions from a Python MatPlotLib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, extract, seaborn

If I have a Python MatPlotLib figure (for example, a *matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot* object), is there a way to extract from it positions of the points and the error bars? I.e. I want to get arrays containing x,y-coordinates and y-errors.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
x = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, 10000)
y = np.random.normal(x**2, np.abs(x) + 1)
p = sb.regplot(x=x, y=y, x_bins=10, fit_reg=None)
```

How can I extract from 'p' positions of the points and the error bars?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The errorbar data are stored in `p.lines`, since seaborn plots them using `plt.plot`.

You can access their positions using `line.get_xdata()` and `line.get_ydata()`.

The point data are stored in `p.collections`, since they are plotted internally in seaborn using `plt.scatter`.

Getting at the point positions from the `PathCollection` object takes one extra step, as shown in this answer: [Get positions of points in PathCollection created by scatter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213889/get-positions-of-points-in-pathcollection-created-by-scatter): i.e. you have to set the `offset_position` first, before accessing the `offsets`.

Here's an example to get both the point data and the errorbar data from the 
 matplotlib `Axes` object, `p`.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, 10000)
y = np.random.normal(x**2, np.abs(x) + 1)
p = sb.regplot(x=x, y=y, x_bins=10, fit_reg=None)

# First, get the positions of the points:
coll = p.collections[0]
coll.set_offset_position('data')

points_xy = coll.get_offsets()
print points_xy
#[[-1.65295679  3.05723876]
# [-1.29981986  1.60258005]
# [-0.94417279  0.8999881 ]
# [-0.56964819  0.38035406]
# [-0.20253243  0.0774201 ]
# [ 0.15535504  0.024336  ]
# [ 0.5362322   0.30849082]
# [ 0.90482003  0.85788122]
# [ 1.26136841  1.66294418]
# [ 1.63048127  3.02934186]]

# Next, get the positions of the errorbars
xerr = []
yerr = []

for line in p.lines:
    xerr.append(line.get_xdata()[0])
    yerr.append(line.get_ydata().tolist())

print xerr
# [-1.6529567859649865, -1.2998198636006264, -0.94417278886439027, -0.56964818931133276, -0.20253243328132031, 0.15535504153419355, 0.53623219583456194, 0.90482002911787607, 1.2613684083224488, 1.6304812696399549]

print yerr
# [[2.908807029542707, 3.200571530218434], [1.4449980200239572, 1.751504207194087], [0.7633753040974505, 1.029774999216172], [0.26593411110949544, 0.4753543268237353], [-0.0030674495857816496, 0.15582564460187567], [-0.052610243112427575, 0.09899773706322114], [0.21019700161329888, 0.41120457637300634], [0.7328000635837721, 0.9826379405190817], [1.508513523393156, 1.8184617796582343], [2.885113765027557, 3.1670479251950376]]

plt.show()
```

Here `points_xy` is a list of `(x,y)` coordinates of the points, `xerr` is the x-coordinate of the errorbars (which is, of course, the same as the x-coordinates in `points_xy`), and `yerr` is a list of pairs of y-coordinates: the top and bottom of each errorbar.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the points are in the center of the error bars (it looks like they are, for this example), then this should do it:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
x = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, 10000)
y = np.random.normal(x**2, np.abs(x) + 1)
p = sb.regplot(x=x, y=y, x_bins=10, fit_reg=None)

def get_data(p):
    x_list = []
    lower_list = []
    upper_list = []
    for line in p.lines:
        x_list.append(line.get_xdata()[0])
        lower_list.append(line.get_ydata()[0])
        upper_list.append(line.get_ydata()[1])
    y = 0.5 * (np.asarray(lower_list) + np.asarray(upper_list))
    y_error = np.asarray(upper_list) - y
    x = np.asarray(x_list)
    return x, y, y_error

get_data(p)
```

Here the returned y_error will be the magnitude of the error bars.

Comment: This does not work for a `FacetGrid` plotted with `seaborn.relplot(kind="line")