# Get Matplotlib scatterplot object

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

How can a previously plotted scatterplot be accessed in Matplotlib ?
For example, for line plots, `get_lines()` will show a list of Line2D objects.

```
>>> ax.get_lines()
<a list of 1 Line2D objects>
```

But this does not capture the Scatter plots. How can I access them ?
There is only one method called scatter but it doesn't appear to do the trick

````
>>> for x in dir(ax):
...     if "scatter" in x:
...         print(x)
...
_parse_scatter_color_args
scatter
>>> ax.scatter
<bound method Axes.scatter of <AxesSubplot:>>
>>> dir(ax.scatter)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__func__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__signature__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__wrapped__']
>>>```

Thanks
````

Comment: I find [Get positions of points in PathCollection created by scatter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213889/get-positions-of-points-in-pathcollection-created-by-scatter) to be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `ax.collections[0].get_offsets().data`. Answer inspired by the link provided by r-beginners.